# Visualize an OWL file with Gruff

Tags: ruby, owl, gruff

How can I load an OWL file in Gruff? It's not clear in the tutorials. I have a file, `camera.owl`. I need to display this in Gruff and view a graph of it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer to this question myself. You need to look under the file menu. File > Load Triples > RDF/XML > File .... Thank you.

Comment: This answer probably isn't useful as it's stated.  If someone has the same problem in the future and finds this question, this might not help them answer it.  Can you provide any more detail?  A screenshot?  Once they find the file menu, what do they need to select?